# Simplifying $s=w_1-c$, where $c=\frac{1}{2}(w_1-t_1+\frac{w_2-t_2}{R})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to solve this easy equation, but can't find the same answer as the correction of the exercise.

We have two equations that I want to simplify (plugging $c$ into $s$)

$$c=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w_1-t_1+\dfrac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

$$s=w_1-c$$

I find:

$$s=w_1-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w_1-t_1+\dfrac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w_1+t_1-\dfrac{w_2+t_2}{R}\right)$$

The correction actually says:

$$s=w_1-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w_1-t_1+\dfrac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(w_1-t_1-\dfrac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

I must be wrong but I don't know why. Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Your simplification seems fine excepting $w_2+t_2$ should be $w_2-t_2$.

Comment: What are the solving variables?

Comment: Both answers, as presented here, are incorrect (in different ways). In *your* answer, the $t_2$ should be negative; in *their* answer, the $t_1$ should be positive. Please check for typographic errors one way or the other, so that we can be sure we're comparing things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first expand a bit to simplify for the coefficient of $w_1$:

$$w_1-\frac{1}{2}\left(w_1-t_1+\frac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right) = w_1-\frac{1}{2}w_1-\frac{1}{2}\left(-t_1+\frac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}w_1-\frac{1}{2}\left(-t_1+\frac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

Factoring $\frac{1}{2}w_1$ by $-\frac{1}{2}$, the expression simplifies to:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-w_1-t_1+\frac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

And factoring by $-1$ yields:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\color{blue}{+}w_1\color{blue}{+}t_1\color{blue}{-}\frac{w_2-t_2}{R}\right)$$

You apparently made a mistake in the numerator of the final fraction. It should be $w_2-t_2$ rather than $w_2+t_2$, but I think it may have been a typo or an accident on your part. The rest is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have some kind of mental block but I still don't get it:

Comment: No problem, I’ll add an extra step!

Comment: Thanks! The $w_2-t_2$ was not a typo but my actual question. I guess I was just confused about the sign change with the fraction.